# Illegal instruction: 4 in ffmpeg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, osx-yosemite

I tried brew installed ffmpeg, i am also tried to compile ffmpeg but in all cases i have the error

> Illegal instruction: 4

I run something like this:

```
./ffmpeg -i /Users/ruslan/Torrents/Weird\ smiling\ dog.3gp -codec:v libx264 -b:v 360k -maxrate 360k -bufsize 720k -movflags +faststart -vprofile high -preset slow -vf 'scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:360' -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -f mp4 -threads 0 -y /dev/null >> /Users/ruslan/erosite/log/ffmpeg_convertation.log 2>&1
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Or only ffmpeg with options when used homebrews installed version

Additional info:

OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2009)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem was resolved when I fully reinstall brew.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen when you restore OS X from Time Machine backup to another computer with different architecture (eg. Haswell to Ivy Bridge). ffmpeg might have been compiled with optimization for a particular architecture. Reinstalling `ffmpeg` worked for me.

`$ brew uninstall ffmpeg && brew install ffmpeg`

If you have multiple version of `ffmpeg` present, run the uninstall command multiple times.

On reinstalling `ffmpeg` was not compiled on my machine but poured from a precompiled bottle.